# TFS merging issue from branch to Trunk

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

We have a Trunk. From this trunk we had taken a branch (V01.01 SP). From this branch (V01.01 SP) we had taken another branch (V01.01.01 REL).

We are implementing the new changes in the branch (V01.01 SP).

After completing the implementation in branch (V01.01 SP) the changes have been merged successfully to the branch (V01.01.01 REL).

After that we have done lot of changes in the branch (V01.01 SP).

Now we want to merge the branch (V01.01.01 REL) to Trunk.

The source is (V01.01.01 REL) and the target is Trunk.

While merging we have found one issue,

some of the changes from the source are not merged to Target.

Instead of that, it takes the content from the target.

It shows the changes in source and target file in a rectangular box. But it automatically ticks the target rectangular box.

How can I changes this to take from source file.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, you could only  merge to directly related branches(parent or child). There is **no merge relationship** between  `branch (V01.01.01 REL)` and `Trunk` in your case (grandparent or grandchild).

You need to pefer a baseless merge, use **[tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command)**.

```
tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive
```

> ***/baseless***
>
> Performs a merge without a base version. That is, allows the user to
>   merge files and folders that do not have a merge relationship. After a
>   baseless merge, a merge relationship exists, and future merges do not
>   have to be baseless.
>
> *Note Baseless merges cannot delete files in the target. You can manually carry over such changes.*